# How to execute a controller/action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to execute an action from within another action?

I'm looking for something in between of 'redirect' and 'render'. I don't want to tell the browser to make an extra request with 'redirect', and 'render' will only execute the view, not the action.

note: I'm using rails 3

@ben-holland Take a look at this http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding

Comment: Something like a partial render?  You can call extra functions you've defined from within a controller action.  I'm not sure what your trying to do...Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Put the action in a lib/ file and include it in both controllers

```
#lib/foo_controller_includes.rb
module FooControllerIncludes
   def special_edit
      do_some_stuff!
      render :action=>"/full/path/to/file"
   end
end

#app/controllers/bar_controller.b
class BarController < ApplicationController
  include FooControllerIncludes

  def edit
     special_edit
  end
end
```